# Why do we need the Abstract Factory pattern?

Tags: clean-architecture

I am reading the chapter 11 page number 90 of clean architecture.
I agree with author that we should use interfaces instead of depending upon the volatile concrete classes to avoid the source code dependency on the concrete class to make our code more modular. He mentions the below pattern to handle the volatile dependency in the code.

[image: Abstract Factory pattern]

In the above image author suggest to use the FactoryServiceImpl to create the instance of the ConcreteImpl.

What's the advantage we get in using the FactoryService? Anyway in the main method we will have to create the instance of FactoryServiceImpl and pass to the Application. Instead we can directly create the instance of the ConcreteImpl and pass it to the Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the advantage we get in using the FactoryService?

The application does not depend on `FactoryServiceImpl` nor `ConcreteImpl`. The advantage is that if you want to test the `application` class you can easily mock the `FactoryService` just by providing a test/mock implementation.

Since the `application` class does not depent on the concrete implentations, it is also not dependent on the dependencies of those classes. E.g. the `FactoryServiceImpl` might contain a dependency to an external service that it passes to the `ConcreteImpl` when it creates it - could also be a database. Maybe the `FactoryServiceImpl` uses a fancy framework that you don't want the application to "indirectly" depent upon.

> Anyway in the main method we will have to create the instance of FactoryServiceImpl and pass to the Application. Instead we can directly create the instance of the ConcreteImpl and pass it to the Application?

Yes you could create a `ConcreteImpl` and pass it to the application, BUT Uncle Bob talks about volatile objects in chapter 11. This means that the application creates `ConcreteImpl` on the fly when it needs it. Maybe a `ConcreteImpl` is stateful and belongs to a user request. It might also be possible that the factory takes arguments that it uses to create a `ConcreteImpl` and this arguments change depending on the application state. Thus the application must create a new `ConcreteImpl` whenever the this state changes. Thus you can not create one instance in the "main" method.